# If statement in Django Model related to an other model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, model

I'm building a Django Python App and I am facing a problem.
For some reason, I would like to implement a different price (Produit.PU_HT_WH) according to the customer (client) type (retailer or wholesaler (booleans). I would like to implement it to my models.py so that I don't have to changes

Models.py (Produit) :

```
class Produit(models.Model):
    id_Prod = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    EAN = models.IntegerField()
    PU_HT_WH = models.FloatField(null=True)
    denomination = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id_Prod
    
    
    def PU_HT(self):
        if self.client.retailer:
            PU_HT= (self.PU_HT_WH/ 0.85) 
        else :
            PU_HT = self.PU_HT_WH
        return PU_HT
```

Models.py (Client) :

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id_Client = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nom_client = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    prenom_client = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    raison_sociale = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    retailer =  models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom_client
```

My goal here is that I just have to replace every " {{prod.PU_HT_WH|floatformat:2}}€ " to " {{prod.PU_HT|floatformat:2}}€ " to display prices according to the customer. The website works only on @login_required so I would like that the customer only sees his price.

I hope that I've been enough understandable ! Thanks for every tips that you could give me :)

I've tried many ways but I always have an error on that line :

```
if self.client.retailer :
```

I don't konw if it is because I am not giving the good boolean check or if it is just impossible to have an if condition regarding to another class , even in an def.

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Could you put a `client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` on the `Produit` model? Or a `OneToOneField()` depending on your needs?

Comment: Hi Jarad, thanks for your answer. I don't think that it is appropriate to had client in my produit model. Both tables aren't connected (they are connected like this : Client -> Order -> OrderDetail <- Product. Does my model Produit knows in my def wich client is selected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Ways:

1. Initialize Product with a member variable called Client. This doesn't need to be a column as client will be decided on runtime.

```
class Product(SafeDeleteModel):
    id_Prod = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    EAN = models.IntegerField()
    PU_HT_WH = models.FloatField(null=True)
    denomination = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __init__(self, client: RandomClient, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.client = client

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id_Prod

    def PU_HT(self):
        PU_HT = self.PU_HT_WH
        if self.client.retailer:
            PU_HT = (self.PU_HT_WH / 0.85)
        return PU_HT
```

tested as follows:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db()
def test_pricing():
    client = RandomClient(retailer=True)
    client.save()
    product = Product(client=client)
    product.PU_HT_WH = 100
    product.EAN = "12345"
    product.save()
    assert product.PU_HT() == 117.64705882352942
```

2. Do this in a class method which takes client as an input.

```
class Product(SafeDeleteModel):
    id_Prod = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    EAN = models.IntegerField()
    PU_HT_WH = models.FloatField(null=True)
    denomination = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id_Prod

    def PU_HT(self, client: RandomClient):
        PU_HT = self.PU_HT_WH
        if client.retailer:
            PU_HT = (self.PU_HT_WH / 0.85)
        return PU_HT
```

tested as:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db()
def test_pricing():
    client = RandomClient(retailer=True)
    client.save()
    product = Product()
    product.PU_HT_WH = 100
    product.EAN = "12345"
    product.save()
    assert product.PU_HT(client) == 117.64705882352942
```

If I were to pick between the two, I'd pick the second method to do this. Product is a separate entity with a few things that change it's behaviour according to the client. The fact that the function takes client as an input is a good indication of this dependence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other solution than creating an intermediary table for associating client, product and price.
Like this :

```
class ClientPrice(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    product = models.Foreignkey(Produit)
    PU_HT_WH = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

The field "Produit.PU_HT_WH" becomes useless.
In the logic of the rest of your app, create prices depending on customers, and change the way you fetch Produit objects in order to get also the price of the currently logged customer.

Comment: Hi 0urz4g, thank you for your help. I'll try it and let you know if it works !

Comment: Please, if my answer helped you, can you consider marking it as accepted or upvoting ? Thank you